# Magento: Get products collection which have atleast one category

Tags: magento

I want to get products collection that have at-least one category. Actually I want to ignore that products which are not in any category. Can anyone help???
My code is below:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
        ->joinField('qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left');

    if ($store->getId()) {
        //$collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
        $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
        $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
        $collection->joinAttribute('name', 'catalog_product/name', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $adminStore);
        $collection->joinAttribute('custom_name', 'catalog_product/name', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $store->getId());
        $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $store->getId());
        $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $store->getId());
        $collection->joinAttribute('price', 'catalog_product/price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());
    }
    else {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    }

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    parent::_prepareCollection();
    $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();

    return $this;
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code snippet:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once("app/Mage.php");
    Mage::app();

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection 
        ->joinField('category_id',
            'catalog_category_product',
            'category_id',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            null,
            'right');
```

The category id can be accessed like:

```
$product->getData('category_id');
```

So it will take all products which id's are in catalog_category_product table, in other words script will take all product in categories.

Load Additional attributes to collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

**UPDATE 1**

I tried with yours - it works perfectly.

Try something this -

```
$collection = $this->_prepareCollection();
$collection 
    ->joinField('category_id',
        'catalog_category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        null,
        'right');
```

Comment: Jake, bundle of thanks for your response. I want to add this filter on products grid. But when I applied your code snippet on grid collection code I got an error (duplicate ids error). :(

Comment: Please put in your first message code snippet where you load your collection. My code loads ALL products which Have any of category.

Comment: Check out UPDATE 1. And if you tell that "I used your code but failed", please tell me which code exactly did you used and how.